# Vue 3: Make other components available inside lazy loaded component (defineAsyncComponent)

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, ionic-framework, components, inject

I have registered a global component via:
app.component('ion-checkbox', IonCheckbox);

But still the component isn't available in any async component like this one:

```
// SOURCE: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html
const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({
        template: '<ion-checkbox mode="ios" value="1" @ionChange="newsletterSubscriptionChanged($event)" labelPlacement="end">Subscribe to newsletter</ion-checkbox>',
      })
    })
)
```

How can inject / provide components in async components?

I'm desperate, I've been trying for 14 hours... :(

Creating a .vue file and importing it like this:

```
const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('./components/AsyncComp.vue')
)
```

is no option because I want to be able to provide / inject components via the "Promise"-Syntax.

Comment: More likely because vue version you use don't have runtime compiler, so string template isn't supported. Possibly could be a better way. Also defineAsyncComponent expects module object, means that it possibly should be `resolve({ default: { ... } })`, needs to be confirmed with trial and error